# Is there a way to cut down my time complexity of O(n^2)?

Tags: performance, algorithm, sorting

I have made a program (hw), which count the frequency of all words.
All of my algorithms takes O(n) or O(n log n), however my word counter takes O(n^2)

The algorithm looks like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < no of elements; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < no of elements; j++)
                if (the ith word == the jth word)
                {
                    increase that word counter by 1;
                    break;
                }
```

The reason i use this way is because the word list is unsorted. So my question is, would it be a good idea to use insertion sort or a sort which can sort the word list in alphebetical order? And how does such kind of sort look like for string array?
The word list is a string array, eg:

```
string words[no of elements]
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Store your words in a binary tree and the complexity of looking up and increasing a word counter gets down to O(log n).

Comment: Insertion sort is O(n^2) in itself, so that's not going to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can sort your elements in O(nlogn) time using any good sorting algorithm like quicksort. Then just check for repeats iterating over sequential elements.

EDIT: in most languages (like C++) the strings can be compared using normal comparison operators. and hence sorted like any array. Moreover, there are usually built-in functions to do so.

Comment: I tried to do Merge sort, but it kept being wrong.
Quicksort i cannot use becuase i need a stable sorter.
Cannot use any built-in algorithm.

Comment: Wauw you were right!
I could just you use the standard way of comparing like if it was an integer. All that time I wasted TT^TT
Thank you a lot!!

Answer (score 2):

Make hash table for your words and then your word count will be O(n) because hast table look up will be O(1).

Comment: This one sounds interesting. Do you know where I can read more about it?

Answer (score 1):

If you can make another data structure, then you can use `map` as well.

Just make a `map<string, int>` of word to count and update it as you iterate through the elements.

(Again O(nlogn) in time complexity)